# Error "could not find function "lmer" using lme4 with MuMIns -package function dredge()

Tags: r, lme4

```r
library(lme4)
library(MuMIn)

fm1 <- lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + (1 | X3), data = df_main)
```

All is good until here, but using dredge as follows:

```r
main_dredge <- dredge(fm1)
```

produces an  error:

```
could not find function "lmer" (model 0 skipped)
could not find function "lmer" (model 1 skipped)
.
.
.

Error in .dredge.par(global.model = fm1) : 
  the result is empty
```

I have tried several models and model types, but all versions produce the same error.

I also used a parallel version of `dredge()`, but I got the same error.

Both parallel and non-parallel version used with models fitted by base `lm()` work just fine.

---

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          2.2
year           2022
month          10
day            31
svn rev        83211
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting

---

R-studio version:
‘2022.7.2.576’

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: The `MuMIn` package does not import `lme4::lmer` (though it `Suggests:` it), but its code does not check to see that it is installed (nor does it call it correctly given that it doesn't require the package be installed). This may be a bug report for the maintainer.

Comment: This is **probably** the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348031/error-when-using-mumin-dredge-function-could-not-find-function-glmmtmb/76348633#76348633 , although the problem *should* only apply to parallelized version ...