# Error when using MuMIn dredge function: could not find function glmmTMB

Tags: r, modeling, glmmtmb

I'm attempting to dredge a model fitted with glmmTMB and keep getting the following warning for each model subset:
"In glmmTMB(... : could not find function "glmmTMB"" and subsequent error: "Error in .dredge.par(global.model = m, evaluate = T, rank = "AIC", m.lim = c(0,  :
the result is empty"

I've tried searching this error but it seems like I'm the only one getting it. I have both the glmmTMB (version 1.1.7) and MuMIn (version 1.47.5) packages loaded and I've updated both of them.

Here is the code I have for the dredge function:

```
library(MuMIn)
library(glmmTMB)
library(parallel)

#first create a cluster to parallelize dredge 
nCores <- detectCores() - 1
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", nCores), type = clusterType))

#model
m <- glmmTMB(Used ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 +  
                 x7 + x8 + x1*x2 + (1|group), data = data, 
                 family = binomial)

options(na.action = "na.fail")
dredged43 <- dredge(m, beta = "sd", evaluate = T, rank = "AIC", m.lim = c(0,9),
                    trace = 2, cluster = clust)
options(na.action = "na.omit")
```

And here is some data for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(101)
data <- data.frame(Used = factor(sample(0:1,size=200,replace=T)),
                   x1=factor(sample(0:1,size=200,replace=T)),x2=rnorm(200),x3=rnorm(200),
                   x4=rnorm(200),x5=rnorm(200),x6=rnorm(200),x7=rnorm(200),
                   x8=rnorm(200), group=factor(rep(1:10,each=20)))
```

I feel like this is probably just some weird error with one of the package versions I have but any advice would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: A similar problem with the lmer package elicted this comment: "The MuMIn package does not import lme4::lmer (though it Suggests: it), but its code does not check to see that it is installed (nor does it call it correctly given that it doesn't require the package be installed). This may be a bug report for the maintainer. – 
r2evans"

Comment: Hmm, @IRTFM, what was the context there? The particular question asked by the OP is fairly straightforward (you do need to know to look at `?pdredge` for the information ...)

Comment: Never mind, found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74641188/error-could-not-find-function-lmer-using-lme4-with-mumins-package-function-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly need something like

```r
clusterEvalQ(clust, library('glmmTMB'))
```

before you issue the `dredge` command.  As the [help file pointed out in the comments](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/MuMIn/html/pdredge.html) indicates,

> All the dependencies for fitting the global.model, including the data and any objects that the modelling function will use must be exported to the cluster worker nodes (e.g. via `clusterExport`). The required packages must be also loaded thereinto (e.g. via `clusterEvalQ(..., library(package)`), before the cluster is used by `pdredge`.

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! I hadn't read the ?pdredge file close enough since R says that function is deprecated now.